# CouchDB delete and replication

Tags: couchdb

I'm having a problem with the replication of my couchDB databases.

I have a remote database which gathers measurement data and replicates it to a central server.
On the server, I add some extra parameters to these documents.

Sometimes, a measurement goes wrong and I just want to delete it.
I do that on the central server and want to replicate it to the remote database.

Since I updated the document on the central server, there is a new revision which isn't synced to the remote.
If I want to delete that measurement, couchdb deletes the latest revision.
Replicating this to the remote doesn't delete the documents on the remote.
(Probably because it doesn't sync the latest revision first, it just wants to delete the latest revision, which isn't on the remote yet).

Replicating the database to the remote before I delete the document fixes this issue.
But sometimes, the remote host is unreachable. I want to be able to delete the document on the central database and make sure that once the remote comes online, it also deletes the document. Is there a way to do this with default couchdb commands?

Answer (score 0):

You could configure continuous replication so that your remote listens for changes on the central database. If it goes offline, and comes back online, re-start continuous replication.